# Programmatically extracting tables from html files with c/c++

Tags: c++, html, c, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm looking for better ideas for extracting tables from html files. Right now I'm using tidy ( http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ ) to convert a html file into xhtml and then I use rapidxml to parse the xml. While parsing I will look for `<table>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` nodes and so create my table data structures.

It works quite nicely but I'm wondering if there are better ways to accomplish my task. Also the tidy lib seems like an abandoned project.

Also has everyone ever tried the "experimental" patch in tidy source code?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: So you're just looking for alternative libraries for XML or HTML parsing?

Comment: I'm looking for ideas to extract tables from html using c or c++.

Comment: While using search at this site, you can specify tags by writing them between square brackets. Look for: `[c++][xml-parsing]`. Ordering results by votes might lead you to more interesting questions.

Comment: I did that for [html-parsing] but I thought I might be a bit more specific and also present one simple solution.

Comment: For such text-munging tasks I'd use Perl...

Comment: I'm with vonbrand in the sense that C and C++ aren't the right tools for solving this type of problem. If you have any choice, use a higher-level language. C++ is a better idea than C, Java would be a better idea than C++, Python would be a better idea than Java...

Answer (score 1):

You can use htmlparser (https://github.com/HamedMasafi/htmlparser)
This lib can parse, read and modify html and css

For example, in your case for reading of table

```cpp
    html_parser html;
    html.set_text(html_text);
    auto table = html.query("#table_id").at(0);
    for (auto tr : table->childs()) {
        for (auto td : tr->childs()) {
            //now here you have a td and you are free to any modify are data read
            //e.g:
            auto td_tag = dynamic_cast<html_tag*>(td);
            td_tag->set_attr("id", "new_id"); // change attr
            auto id = td_tag->attr("id");
            auto test = td_tag->innser_text();
            auto html = td_tag->outter_html();
        }
    }
```

The quick start sample is [here](https://github.com/HamedMasafi/htmlparser/blob/master/main.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is quite ok. I think the best is to tidy and convert the html to xhtml and parse the xml. Cannot see how it can be simplified.

You did not mention any problems so I am not sure what the issue is.